# I am unable to set expiration time using Python redis module

Tags: python, redis

Platform:

- Windows 11 Pro x64 zh_CN
- Python version: 3.9.12 MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)
- Redis version: 5.0.14.1 x64
- Python redis module version: 4.5.1

**Problem**: I'm unable to set expiration time (unix timestamp format) using Python redis module

**Question** : is this a bug of the Python redis module, or just my redis server and python redis module is incompatible?

**Code** for method 1 and 2
(*Notice* variable key is a random string)

```
redis_pool_session = redis.ConnectionPool(host=app_config.APP_REDIS_SERVER_HOST, port=app_config.APP_REDIS_SERVER_PORT, db=app_config.APP_REDIS_DB_SESSION_NO, password=app_config.APP_REDIS_SERVER_PASSWORD, decode_responses=True)
conn = redis.Redis(connection_pool=redis_pool_session)
```

Method #1:

```
conn.set("JIE_DEMO_" + key, value, exat=1677298679)
```

Method #2:

```
conn.set("JIE_DEMO_" + key, value)
conn.expireat("JIE_DEMO_" + key, 1677298679)
```

Redis-CLI:

```
EXPIREAT "JIE_DEMO_" + key 1677298679
```

Error:

for method #1:

> redis.exceptions.ResponseError: syntax error

for method #2:

> program return with code 0, but actually completely not working.

If querying its expiring time on redis-cli, TTL is still -1(permanent)

Redis-CLI is working properly.

Answer (score -1):

version issue：
History
Starting with Redis version 2.6.12: Added the EX, PX, NX and XX options.
Starting with Redis version 6.0.0: Added the KEEPTTL option.
Starting with Redis version 6.2.0: Added the GET, EXAT and PXAT option.
Starting with Redis version 7.0.0: Allowed the NX and GET options to be used together.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).